# How to inject a PNG into a buffer in image-mode from a process output

Tags: process, image-mode

I'm the maintainer of [`puml-mode`](https://github.com/skuro/puml-mode), a major mode for editing [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/) files. It works by submitting the content of the current buffer to an external Java process, PlantUML, which then outputs an image to stdout. This image is then put in a newly created buffer to display.

While it correctly works for both SVG and ASCII art outputs, when I try to produce a PNG something goes wrong and the new buffer shows empty, with no error messages whatsoever. The weird thing is that when I `C-c C-c` in the image buffer, I actually see the PNG as text, so the image is supposedly properly loaded.

When I manually open PNG files they correctly display as images.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```el
(defun puml-is-image-output-p ()
  "Return true if the diagram output format is an image, false if it's text based."
  (not (equalp 'utxt
               (puml-output-type)))) ;; << feature detection, either 'png 'svg or 'utxt

(defun puml-preview-sentinel (ps event)
  "For the PlantUML process (as PS) reacts on the termination event (as EVENT)."
  (if (equal event "finished\n")
      (progn
        (switch-to-buffer puml-preview-buffer)
        (when (and (display-images-p)
                   (puml-is-image-output-p))
          (image-mode)))
    (warn "PUML Preview failed: %s" event)))
```

Comment: While not exactly an answer to your question. Is there any problem in actually storing the output of planetuml to a file and displaying it?

Comment: @IqbalAnsari that would introduce some maintenance concerns (e.g. cleanup) which I would rather avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let bound `coding-system-for-read` to `raw-text` or `no-conversion` in function starting the process for getting png data. This will instruct emacs to treat the process output as raw bytes.

Looking at your code in github it seems the `puml-preview` starts the `planetuml` process, change its definition as follows

```el
(defun puml-preview ()
  "Preview diagram."
  (interactive)
  (let ((b (get-buffer puml-preview-buffer)))
    (when b
      (kill-buffer b)))
  (let ((process-connection-type nil)
        (buf (get-buffer-create puml-preview-buffer))
        (coding-system-for-read 'raw-text))
    (let ((ps (start-process "PUML" buf
                             "java" "-jar" (shell-quote-argument puml-plantuml-jar-path)
                             (puml-output-type-opt) "-p")))
      (process-send-region ps (point-min) (point-max))
      (process-send-eof ps)
      (set-process-sentinel ps 'puml-preview-sentinel))))
```

Comment: That was it! Just an extra note: I also had to let `(coding-system-for-write 'binary)`, but your lead was simply essential

Comment: Glad I could help. I don't think you need to set `coding-system-for-write` unless you are saving the image file

Comment: Testing it by hand, without setting it for write it would still display a blank buffer